# How can I export the data from the Neo4j sandbox to my own Neo4j database on Ubuntu system?

Tags: neo4j

I am a user of Neo4j Sandbox for "Network and IT Management":https://neo4j.com/sandbox-v2/, now I want to import the data of Neo4j Sandbox for "Network and IT Management" to own Neo4j database.

Answer (score 1):

Send an email to support team of neo4j saying you need the data of neo4j sandbox and why you need it at
**devrel@neo4j.com** (support email given on the neo4j snadbox page)

Support team will contact through email and may give a link to download the backup of that specific sandbox which you can use to restore it on your neo4j server using

```
neo4j-admin restore
```

commad

if that command fails then follow
@PawanWagh's reply [here](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/12041)
on github issues page to restore the backup on your neo4j server

*late reply still it just worked for me may help someone in future*

Answer (score 0):

Using the Sandbox,and select all the data you needed,and then you will find a label on the queries result "Export CSV",then you got the data.enter image description here